# System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException : Callback routine requested an abort Execution was aborted by the user

Tags: unit-testing, fluent-nhibernate

Upgraded to the latest version of NHibernate and now some of my unit tests are failing where I'm using the SQLite InMemory library.  Here is what I upgraded

- FluentNHibernate 1.2.0.712 ==> 2.0.3
- NHibernate 3.1.0.4000 ==> 4.0.4.4000
- Iesi.Collections 3.1.0.4000 ==> 4.0.1.4000

Now the following code compiles but no longer works correctly.

```
 var cfg = Fluently.Configure()
                   .Database(SQLiteConfiguration.Standard.InMemory().ShowSql())
                   .BuildConfiguration();
 cfg.BuildSessionFactory();
```

I get the following error every time.

> > SetUp : System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException : Callback routine requested an abort
> >     Execution was aborted by the user

Has anyone else experienced this during an upgrade and found a way around it?  My timeline is rather tight so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting a response from another developer on the problem they asked me what version of System.Data.SQLite DLL that I was using. It turns out that I was using version 1.0.60.0.  This reference happened to be hard coded to a downloaded copy of the DLL.  I removed the reference from the project and then added the Nuget package which installed version 1.0.98.1

```
<package id="System.Data.SQLite.Core" version="1.0.98.1" targetFramework="net45" />
```

After installing this package and then recompiling, the unit tests ran fine from Visual Studio but not using the Msbuild.exe command line.  This was needed for the continuous build server.  It wasn't until I change the reference mode from the default **CopyLocal = False** to **CopyLocal = True**

[image: System.Data.SQLite Copy Local Action]

This creates the sub folders x86 and x64 that contain the "SQLite.Interop.Dll" that is needed when doing a rebuild.  This allowed the unit tests to work correctly on my machine.  For the Constant Integration (CI) server, I needed to add a built step that would copy these two folders to the output folder.

```
<PreBuildEvent>xcopy $(SolutionDir)\packages\System.Data.SQLite.Core.1.0.98.1\build\net45\* $(TargetDir) /S /V /Y</PreBuildEvent>
```

This allowed the CI server to copy the files to the output folder for unit testing.

While I feel *foolish* for not updating the System.Data.SQLite.DLL when I updated the rest of the NHibernate solution, hopefully this question will prevent someone else from making the same mistake.